# Can someone explain/annotate this Ruby snippet with comments?

Tags: ruby

Please explain this Ruby code so I can convert it to PHP:

```
data = Hash.new({})
mysql_results.each { |r| data[r['year']][r['week']] = r['count'] }

(year_low..year_high).each do |year|
  (1..52).each do |week|
   puts "#{year} #{week} #{data[year][week]}"
  end
end
```

Comment: There's a bug here: data hash won't be updated by the second line because it in fact changes the default hash value.

Comment: @Mladen, comment++.  It *is* a damning bug.  It will *appear* to work if the range of years is a single year, or if the weeks in `(year, week)` tuples don't overlap, because access will return the same mutated default hash.  The original coder may never have known -- s/he certainly doesn't call `data.keys()`, which would be empty, even though `data[year]` returns something meaningful...

Comment: @Mladen: very correct.  Default hash values can lead to funky bugs.  Sorry to put this all on one line, but this is probably a better strategy (if my guess about the desired behavior is correct):  `h = {}; [[2010, 5, 3], [2010,6,27]].each { |r| h[r[0]] = {} if !h.has_key?(r[0]); h[r[0]][r[1]] = r[2] }`

Comment: @Benjamin, simpler formulation:  `data = Hash.new { |me, key| me[key] = {} }`.

Comment: @pilcrow:  Nice.  I tried to do something like that at first, but just decided on the `has_key?` route.  Updated:  `h = Hash.new { |me, key| me[key] = {} }; [[2010, 5, 3], [2010,6,27]].each { |r| h[r[0]][r[1]] = r[2] }`.

Comment: Actually, I'd avoid two-dimensional hash altogether and just make it ordinary hash indexed by `[year, week]` pair, so: `h = {} ... h[[r[:year], r[:week]]] = r[:count]`, makes your life simpler. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = Hash.new({})
# create hash 'data'
mysql_results.each { |r| data[r['year']][r['week']] = r['count'] }
# maps each row from sql query to hash like this: data[2010][30] = 23
# So you can access 'count' from every year and week in very simple way

(year_low..year_high).each do |year|
# for (year = year_low; year <= year_high; year++) 
  (1..52).each do |week|
  # for (week = 1; week <=52; week++)
   puts "#{year} #{week} #{data[year][week]}"
   # printf("%d %d %d\n", year, week, data[year][week]);
  end
end
```

Sorry for mixing C with pseudo code, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Second line in php does this: foreach($mysql_results as $row) { $data[$row['year']][$row['week']] = $row['count']; }

Answer (score 1):

The first bit is just forming an array like so:

```
$data[2009][17] = 10;
```

PHP equivalent of that would be:

```
foreach ($mysql_results as $r){
  $data[$r['year']][$r['week']] = $r['count'];
}
```

The second part would equate to the following:

```
foreach(range($year_low, $year_high) as $year){
  foreach(range(1, 52) as $week){
    print $year.' '.$week.' '.$data[$year][$week]
  }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: +1 for remembering the `range()` function. I always forget, and resort to a simple `for()` instead..

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();

#Build an array of 'count' per year/week
foreach($mysql_results as $r) {
    $data[$r['year']][$r['week']] = $r['count'];
}

#Loop through the $data variable, printing out the 'count' for each year in the array,
#and all 52 weeks that year
for($year = $year_min; $year <= $year_max; $year++) {
    for($week=1; $week<=52; $week++) {
        echo "$year $week {$data[$year][$week]}";
    }
}
```

Note that year_low and year_high are variables undefined in the current snippet, but they should be known to you.

Also, $mysql_results should be an array containing all rows returned by the database.

In short, the following code does this:

- Make an array grouped per year, then per week, containing the value 'count'
- Loop through this array, displaying, in order, the year, the week, and the value for 'count', if any